# how to set user agent in an xml document?

Tags: xml, httprequest, user-agent

please help me!
how to set user agent in a simple xml document?
I have a document and need to allow one user agent to access this document.
How do I set this in a simple XML document? 
can please give me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An XML document has nothing to do with HTTP headers. To deliver this XML document to you must use an HTTP server. Settings the user agent has to be done at the HTTP server and it highly depends on what deployment you are using.

Comment: hi Dirkk, thanks for your answer.  My XML is generated by php.
I need to allow one user agent to access this document. 

with ini_set is possible to generate this XML with due authorization from the user agent?
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)');

???

Comment: @Renata Please use a decent search engine. I have no knowledge of PHP and I just google "php set http header" and it came up with multiple responses. Seems like `header()` is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

dirkk answered your question, but for testing purposes you can control the user agent header on the client side with curl:

```
curl -A "Hey now!/5.0" http://your.example.com
```